# Help interpreting limits with the Lambert $W$ function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lambert-w

So let's say I have some function $f(x)$ where both $f(x)$ and $x$ are constrained to be real positive integers, $1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

I was trying to find potential limits of this function. I realized that given those conditions, $f(x)$ will always be greater than $\ln(f(x))$.

So, I set:
$f(x) > \ln(f(x))$

And, if I solve this for $f(x)$, I get the following steps

$$f(x) > \ln(f(x))$$

$$e^{f(x)} > f(x)$$

$$1 > f(x)e^{-f(x)}$$

$$-1 < -f(x)e^{-f(x)}$$

$$W(-1) < -f(x)$$

$$-W(-1) > f(x)$$

And because $-W(-1)$ appears to be an upper limit, and with the integer constraint then

$$\lfloor -W(-1) \rfloor \geq f(x)$$

But $W(-1)$ is a complex number... how am I supposed to understand what this is saying?

Comment: I think the problem arrises when you apply $W$ to the inequality assuming it's increasing and always real-valued.

Comment: Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. It's only possible for $W$ to output a real value if $x\geq- \frac{1}{e}$. Since $-1$ is clearly $<-\frac{1}{e}$, the answer won't be real so you can't apply $W$ to the inequality in the first place.

Comment: I kinda wondered if that was the case, but the original construction of the problem does appear to be true. That is $f(x) > ln(f(x))$, so where did the problem go awry? There's clearly a math error in there. But getting to the point where $-1<-f(x)e^{-f(x)}$ doesn't seem to be it. Not to mention, if f(x) = 1, it's lowest value, then the above becomes $-1<-e^{-1}$ and this is $-1 < -\frac{1}{e}$ which is definitely true.

Comment: I realized about 20 minutes after posting the last comment that $-\frac{1}{e}$ should be the lower limit as when I plug in the lowest value for $f(x)$, that's what I get. This is a real value for the W function. So that's my answer to the specific $f(x)$ I've been using. But @mohamedshawky definitely has the more complete idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $-1<-f(x)e^{-f(x)}$.

The problem is when you say $W(-1)<W\left(-f(x)e^{-f(x)}\right)=-f(x)$.

This is only possible if $W(x)$ is increasing, real-valued and defined at both values for the inequality.

For example, if we have $-1<0$, we can't say $\sqrt{-1}<\sqrt 0\equiv i<0$ (not real-valued).

Another example is for $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x+1}$, we can't say $-1<0\implies f(-1)<f(0)\equiv -\frac{1}{0}<-1$ (not defined).

Another example is $f(x)=-x$, we can't say $-1<0\implies f(-1)<f(0)\equiv 1<0$, but we should say $f(-1)>f(0)\equiv 1>0$ because $f(x)$ is decreasing not increasing.

The problem is not when you apply $W$ to $-f(x)e^{-f(x)}$, but when you apply it to $-1$ because it's not real-valued there.